# Implementing Smooth, Rounded Trajectory Animation in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, graphics, android-jetpack-compose

I’m working on a Kotlin project using Jetpack Compose where I need to animate a box object moving between an infinite number of points. The trajectory should be a closed path, with the first and last points connecting to form a loop. The goal is for the object to follow a trajectory with rounded corners, so that when it changes direction, the transition is smooth rather than abrupt.

So far, I haven’t found any tools within Jetpack Compose that can help me achieve this. The closest I’ve come is Catmull-Rom spline interpolation, but it’s quite complex to implement.

Below is a screenshot for reference. The current direction of the object’s movement is indicated in red, while the desired movement is shown by a green dash-dotted line.

[image]

Here is the code I have so far (This code moves the object around sharp corners, but I want to make the corners rounded instead):

```
@Composable
fun RoundingMovementAnimation() {
    val infiniteTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition(label = "")
    val fraction = infiniteTransition.animateFloat(
        initialValue = 0f,
        targetValue = 1f,
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(2000, easing = LinearEasing),
            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Restart
        ), label = ""
    )

    //These points are indicated for demonstration purposes; their number will change dynamically in the final version
    val points = listOf(Offset(100f, 100f), Offset(300f, 300f), Offset(100f, 300f))

    val segmentLength = 1f / points.size
    val currentSegment = (fraction.value / segmentLength).toInt()
    val segmentFraction = (fraction.value % segmentLength) / segmentLength

    val currentPoint = lerp(points[currentSegment], points[(currentSegment + 1) % points.size], segmentFraction)

    BoxWithConstraints {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .offset(currentPoint.x.dp, currentPoint.y.dp)
                    .height(50.dp)
                    .width(50.dp)
                    .background(Color.Red)
                    .zIndex(600f)
            ) {}
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun RoundingMovementAnimationPreview() {
    RoundingMovementAnimation()
}
```

My question is: How can I implement a smooth, rounded trajectory for an animated object in Jetpack Compose in a simpler way?